# Toggle a bootstrap dropdown with Knockout click binding

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

Is it possible to use knockout to trigger the bootstrap dropdown function?

I've made a jsfiddle to highlight the problem:

### [Sample JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzf4v/11/)

This bit toggles the menu and makes is visible on load:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');
```

When I use the same code inside the knockout `buttonClick` function, the menu will toggle as intended but it will toggle one more time and stay hidden.

In the jsfiddle I've hooked up on the bootstrap shown event with an alert, there you can see that the menu actually toggles.

**The question:**

How can force the menu to toggle only once? Or should I use a different approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an issue with the click event on the button. The fix is to add `clickBubble: false` to the `data-bind` on your button. I think your event is bubbling up so it is toggling on and off immediately, so you wouldn't see it.

Check out the working sample:

### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jzf4v/14/)

**Markup:**

```
<div class="dropdown" id="myDropdown"> 
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu</a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>Here goes stuff</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<button data-bind="click: buttonClick, clickBubble: false">Button</button>
```

**JS:**

```
var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.buttonClick = function(){
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

### [Knockout Reference](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html)

> **Note 4: Preventing the event from bubbling**
>
> By default, Knockout will allow the click event to continue to bubble
>   up to any higher level event handlers. For example, if your element
>   and a parent of that element are both handling the click event, then
>   the click handler for both elements will be triggered. If necessary,
>   you can prevent the event from bubbling by including an additional
>   binding that is named clickBubble and passing false to it, as in this
>   example:

Answer (score -1):

I've had no issue doing this on Firefox 31.
Your code works actually.

What is your configuration ?

Comment: I use chrome. But I tested in firefox as well after your comment and it still doesnt work for me. After the alert box is displayed, the menu will close again.Click on the "menu" text and compare behaviour :)

Comment: This is not an answer. I know you cannot comment as of yet, but I'd remove this otherwise it is likely to be down voted and/or flagged for deletion.